# Linq Reverse string c#

Tags: c#, linq

I want to reverse a string as given in the example.

```
 string[] actor = new string[] { "amitabh", "abhishek", "jitendra", "Salman", "Aishwariya" };

 var  resultstring= actor.Reverse().Select(c => c.Reverse()).ToArray();

    foreach(var m in resultstring)
    {
     //how to fetch this?
    }
```

the output should be

> ayirawhsia,namlas,ardnetij,kehsihba,hbatima

Most of the post mentioned on how to reverse without using built in reverse().

I need the result using only reverse built in function using linq.
I am able to make it as shown in the above snippet but couldnt reach the end.

Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: @VijayKumbhoje, Ammu specifically said he isn't interested in that question because it does this without the built in reverse function, whereas he wants to use the built in function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var resultstring = actor.Reverse().Select(c => c.Reverse()).ToArray();
```

To this:

```
var resultstring = actor.Reverse().Select(c => new string(c.Reverse().ToArray())).ToArray();
```

Of note here is the fact that when you called `Reverse` on the string it actually returned an `IEnumerable<char>` when you were probably expecting a `string`. No problem, the `string` constructor accepts an array of `char` which is what my tweak to your code does.

Comment: An explanation of why this works better than his would be very helpful here

Comment: It works. i missed *new string * . any difference between 
var resultstring = actor.Reverse().Select(c => new string(c.Reverse().ToArray())).ToArray();   and var resultstring = actor.Reverse().Select(c => new string(c.Reverse().ToArray()));  for both the cases im able to fetch the records in the for loop.

Comment: @Ammu You can safely drop that last call to `ToArray`. I just put it because you did.

Answer (score 2):

If the output is the only thing desired, this is enough

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", actor).Reverse().ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish that i've broke it down into:

1. Enumerate on every cell.
2. Reverse the current string
3. Converted it into char array.
4. And the overloaded `string constructor` which accept `char array`.
5. Iterate and print every string.

**Code:**

```
var actor = new[] { "amitabh", "abhishek", "jitendra", "Salman", "Aishwariya" };

var resultstring = actor.Reverse().Select(c => new string(c.Reverse().ToArray()));
foreach (var m in resultstring)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m);
}
```

Comment: Your code output does not match his example output because in his sample he both reversed the names and reversed the order in which they come out, whereas yours only reverses each name and not the order. I don't know whether or not he actually cares about the reversal of order, but it would be worth finding out

Comment: The OP also needs to reverse the order of the strings as well as the order of the characters in the string.